# Benchmark turned out inconclusive, need help troubleshooting

Tags: benchmarking

I just got a new CPU/Mobo/RAM after a long overdue upgrade. Everything boots and seems to be working normal. My last upgrade will be a new GPU but not right now, so in the meantime I ran a userbenchmark test, but it came out as inconclusive. I'm not sure how to tackle this one, nothing online seems to help.

Results: https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/30457360

Comment: Your "3200" RAM is operating as 2133. Check your firmware settings for an [AMP](https://www.eteknix.com/amd-introduces-its-xmp-equivalent-amp) memory setting.

Comment: It is also possible that your RAM is operating in single channel mode. You can find out if this is the case using CPU-z. You may need to change what slots the memory sticks are in.

Comment: Thank you @Mokubai, did the trick, still says incomplete, but I think this is now because of the bottleneck my current gpu might cause. https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/30559863 thanks!

Comment: If there was something specific that you did that fixed it then feel free to post an answer saying what you did. You should be able to self-answer and mark it as correct and it may help future visitor that have a similar problem. My comments were mostly just "hints" as I don't know what the specific settings for AMD boards is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mokubai's comment was on point.

RAM was operating at a lower timing that advertised. For an Gigabyte MOBO, on boot press DEL to jump into bios settings. Look for Extreme Memory Profile and select Profile 1, Save and Exit.